# Unix Scripting to read CSV file then change format

Tags: sql, unix, csv

I'm new to unix scripting and would appreciate some direction or help. I want to make a script that reads through a csv file containing Information similar to below.

```
Business Group  Used Disk Space (GB)    Disk Quota (GB)  Grace Period
EandT-Mech  35403.4                   37434.2              none
Rotatives-AD    6.40E-05                      524.288              none
Nacelles-Mech   0.056832                      1677.72              none
```

then I need to in that same script once it' either read or reading change it into this format:

```
INSERT INTO Storage (b_group, used_space, disk_quota, grace_period)
VALUES (‘TSandD-Aero’,6.40E-05,734.003, ‘none’);
INSERT INTO Storage (b_group, used_space, disk_quota, grace_period)
VALUES (‘EDS-Admin’,192.076,3568.01, ‘none’);
```

so just change the values with the 4 information below to whatever has been read in on the csv file.

so to sum up, read csv file, put into sql formit and commit that into my database, any help or direction to get me going would be appreicated as I can't find anything similar online.

Comment: This doesn't look like a csv, it looks like it's either tab delimited or constant column width. Either way, have you tried `cut` or `awk`?

Comment: Awk??? Perl at least. Also your DBMS probably has a bulk-import tool which can do this out of the box.

Comment: @cha0site [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) has "comma" in its name, but usually describes a "delimiter seperated file". In fact, excel (for example) uses tabs as delimiter when you select "[CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)" as target format.

Comment: its data I've copied from a csv file that was in excel so its tabbed delimeter then, I will give them a go and let you know how I get on and im using psql database so I've got no import tools on it I believe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

COPY storage from '/h/u544835/dehpc14_Disk_Quota_Report.csv' DELIMITERS ',' CSV;

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat input.txt | awk 'NR>1{printf "INSERT INTO Storage(b_group, used_space, disk_quota, grace_period)\nVALUES(\"%s\", %s, %s, \"%s\");\n",$1,$2,$3,$4}' | tr '"' "'"

INSERT INTO Storage(b_group, used_space, disk_quota, grace_period)
VALUES('EandT-Mech', 35403.4, 37434.2, 'none');
INSERT INTO Storage(b_group, used_space, disk_quota, grace_period)
VALUES('Rotatives-AD', 6.40E-05, 524.288, 'none');
INSERT INTO Storage(b_group, used_space, disk_quota, grace_period)
VALUES('Nacelles-Mech', 0.056832, 1677.72, 'none');
```

Comment: Sorry kev could you explain how thats done? I was looking at
http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/COPY
and thought I could use the /i to read in a script file that copies in to table storage how I would need it to if you have any ideas?

Comment: It's just basic `awk` command: **`$2` is field#2**. I'm not familiar with `postgresql`. Sorry, I couldn't give you any further advice.

Comment: as I'm a new user and can't answer my own question yet I will post it here:
from within postGreSQL all I need to simply do is

\i h/location/runtestscript

in that script all I do is say

delete from storage;
COPY storage from '/h/u544835/dehpc14_Disk_Quota_Report.csv' DELIMITERS ',' CSV;



so i delete all ones in there, then re-add the file as that gets updated every 6 hours when I need to, so my data can stay fresh.